# Window casing upgrade to plastic/pvc/vinyl/aluminum

Tags: windows, pvc, condensation, aluminum

I Just had  two rooms added to the house, and I totally forgot to mention in the contract that I wanted the window casing  to be plastic.
(*window frame? The internal part that encases the window basically*)

The contractor installed a wood frame, and only agreed to paint it with a separate latex based paint for a bit of extra protection.

I am now looking for a way to do a bit more without too much effort - find a set of plastic or aluminum panels and glue them on top of the wood maybe.

Since I've never really done anything like this, I have questions:

Does this make sense at all?

What paneling (*search terms are most welcome*) would be thin enough to fit in there?

What type of glue?

If you know of alternative approaches, I'll be happy to hear about those too.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this the _interior_ or _exterior_ portion of the sill? Maybe edit your post to include a picture with a hand, ruler or digital arrow pointing to the part you're talking about. This sounds very much like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is it, exactly, that you're trying to accomplish? There may be a better/easier way of accomplishing it that you're not aware of.

Comment: This is the interior part I'm talking about. I am looking for a better way to protect the window casing than just painting it

Comment: Unless this is some special situation, it's unlikely that the _interior_ window sill will take much damage. Of course, if you have dogs who like to put their feet up there to look (and bark) out the window, their claws can damage the wood, and in that case, an aluminum cover, while not looking spectacular, would be replaceable more easily than replacing/repairing wood. PVC wouldn't hold up well to dogs at all, I'd think.

Comment: Nothing special, just normal Canadian weather, with high humidity during the summer (I live on an island) and lots of window condensation during the winter. I'm primarily worried about water damage, the dogs I have are too small to reach these windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are set on PVC then it is probably best if you remove the wood casing and install new PVC casing.

It will be as much (*or more*) work to hack something on (*and may look hacked*).  Starting over  will end up being better looking and easier.

There are multitudes of "How to Case a window" videos on the YouTube. ( *watch many not just one*)  [Here is One](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=53HPNYutTVg).

Answer (score 1):

Adding plastic or aluminum on top of a wooden windowframe is likely to just be an ugly mess and may rot the wooden frame by trapping moisture.

Accept that you may need to paint them once in a while, they'll probably last longer just painted.